Unexpected Behavior in cts search with and without Whitespace Sensitivity - MarkLogic
We have two XML documents with the following elements:
<!-- Document 1 -->

<LegacyCode>09Y14K012D3001</LegacyCode>

<!-- Document 2 -->

<LegacyCode>09 14 012 3001</LegacyCode>

I'm using the following cts:search query to fetch these documents:
cts:search(
  doc(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("XYZ"),
    cts:word-query("*09*14*012*3001*", ("punctuation-insensitive", "whitespace-insensitive", "wildcarded"))
  ))
)

However, this query does not return the expected documents. Interestingly, if I use the "whitespace-sensitive" option, it successfully retrieves the documents.
Index Settings:
The following index settings are enabled:

word searches

fast phrase searches

fast case-sensitive searches

fast diacritic-sensitive searches

trailing wildcard searches

trailing wildcard word positions

three-character searches

three-character word positions

two-character searches

one-character searches


What is causing this search behavior? Given that "whitespaces" do not seem to be playing any part here, why is the "whitespace-insensitive" option failing to fetch the documents while "whitespace-sensitive" succeeds?

Your second document LegacyCode element has a text() value that will be tokenized and indexed as multiple "words", but the first document will have one "word".
cts:word-query() with wildcard and whitespace-insensitive may not be doing what you want/expect.
Rules for Wildcard Searches


Spaces are used as word breaks, and wildcard matching only works within a single word. For example, m*th* will match "method" but not "meet there".

If the query has the whitespace-sensitive option, then whitespace is treated as word characters. This can be useful for matching spaces in wildcarded value queries. You can use the whitespace-sensitive option in wildcarded word queries, too, although it might not make much sense, as it will match more than you might expect.



So, if you have wildcards and want to match on multiple "words" in a word-query, then whitespace-sensitive would need to be used in order to match both documents.
If you know that you want to target the LegacyCode element and the value you are looking for is the only text in that element, then you might want to look at cts:element-value-query() or cts:field-value-query() instead of cts:word-query().

Thanks Mads Hansen for your reply. But still it does not explain why the first document was not fetched. Even with "whitespace-insensitive" it should have been fetched - as it is a single word
